# Given only entity ID, how do I tell whether it is page/app/user?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

For example, if I am given ID `128740590570428` and query http://graph.facebook.com/128740590570428, how do I tell if this is a page, user or an app?

Comment: guessing: may be you could use the link

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla Well, that's not exactly the API way. Assuming what you've meant was attempt to check different URLs https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=# etc.

Comment: sorry for the incomplete response, I was talking about the link attribute in the results of http://graph.facebook.com/128740590570428 . Because in the link it says its an app

Comment: Right. That will not say app if the app has namespace. Furthermore, https://www.facebook.com/anuary can be either page or user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add metadata=1 to the get params. 'type' will be in the metadata.

Eg.
http://graph.facebook.com/128740590570428?metadata=1

Answer (score 0):

From facebook graph API documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

All objects are accessed in the same way, so using graph api, probably you cannot tell if the give ID returns an User,Page or Event object.

[image]

You will have to write rules yourself inorder to recognize the type of object from the result.
I hope this helps.

Thank you